# Stretching a XAML Path to fill its containing element

Tags: xaml, path, controltemplate, stretch

I have a `ControlTemplate` with some `Path`s in it. I would like the `Path`s to stretch and fill the control they are in, such as a `Button`. How can I do this?

What I have currently looks like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplate" TargetType="Button">
    <Canvas Background="AliceBlue">
        <Path Data="M 99.5,50 A 49.5,49.5 0 1 1 0.5,50 A 49.5,49.5 0 1 1 99.5,50 z"
            Fill="White" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
        <Path Data="M 15,50 C 17.5,22.5 47.5,22.5 50,50 C 52.5,77.5 82.5,77.5 85,50"
            Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
    </Canvas>
</ControlTemplate>

...

<Button Template="{StaticResource SomeTemplate}" Height="120" Width="120" />
```

I am aware of `ScaleTransform`'s `StrechX` and `StretchY` attributes, but they are only proportional scaling of the original `Path`'s size.

Would I use a value converter? Or perhaps some form of relative binding to the parent's size?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Throwing a ViewBox around the Canvas in your example should work.

Comment: This is awesome, worked for me as well.  I do wish I understood *why* throwing a ViewBox around a Canvas or Path fixed the fact that the Paths weren't stretching, though.

Comment: Well, basically, because that's what `Viewbox`is for. :-) To stretch something that has its intrinsic size (like a `Path` or a `Canvas`) to the size of its container.

Answer (score 5):

To stretch a Path use the `Stretch` property. It works just like image stretching - described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx (System.Windows.Media > Stretch Enumeration). In the case shown below, setting the value to `Uniform` will preserve the path width-height ratio filling the control which it occupies so that the whole path is visible.

```
<Path Stretch="Uniform" Data="..."/>
```

There is a side-effect: Stretching a Path this way will "normalize" its data i.e. even if the data would be written so that all the points are transformed from the origin [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAEDM.png)], when stretch the transform is omitted [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2gkK.png)] (hope i'm explaining this clearly).

You can use this to your advantage when having a messy object from Inkscape for example (not transformed to the origin) not worrying about the transformed data.

[image: Stretch="none" (default) - same as not using this property. Notice the data not having single point in the origin]

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="200">
  <TextBlock Text="(0,0)" />
  <TextBlock Text="(200,200)" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
  <Path Stroke="Blue" Stretch="None" Fill="Beige" Data="M 63,50 82,86 107,62 84,65 Z"/>
  <Rectangle Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: Stretch="Uniform"]

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="200">
  <TextBlock Text="(0,0)" />
  <TextBlock Text="(200,200)" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
  <Path Stroke="Blue" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Beige" Data="M 63,50 82,86 107,62 84,65 Z"/>
  <Rectangle Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.